# PHP number: decimal point visible only decimal point

Tags: php

> PHP number: decimal point visible only if needed

This Example using i want to 105.54  "-" Rremove

```
$foo = "-105.5457";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');
want to 105.54
```

Comment: Problem is rounding? You need 'false rounded value', i guess -> 105.54, not 105.55?

Comment: Since $foo is string, treat is as string: $foo = "-105.5457";
echo substr($foo,1,6); This will give you expected output....

Comment: I Want To Added New Feature if  value=" -" Then 150.55.Cr Or "+" Then 150.55.Dr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not clear enough...

```
echo number_format(abs((float)$foo), 2, '.', '');
```

?

Comment: I Want To Added New Feature if  value=" -" Then 150.55.Cr Or "+" Then 150.55.Dr

Answer (score 1):

Try use [abs()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) "Returns the absolute value of number. " :)

Comment: I Want To Added New Feature if  value=" -" Then 150.55.Cr Or "+" Then 150.55.Dr

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$foo = "-105.5457";
echo number_format(str_replace('-','',$foo),2,'.','');
```

Comment: I Want To Added New Feature if  value=" -" Then 150.55.Cr Or "+" Then 150.55.Dr

Comment: So  use `strpos` 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php